# vs 2017 не добавляются свойства классов bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap4, package

использую VS 2017. Скачал `Bootstrap 4.2.1`, подключил в клиентских библиотеках и скачал jQuery 3.3.0 и popper.js 1.14.0.

libman:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "jquery@3.3.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery/"
    },
    {
      "library": "popper.js@1.14.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/popper.js/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "unpkg",
      "library": "bootstrap@4.2.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь идем во View и пытаемся использовать класс m-4

```
@model IEnumerable<TestForNewStyle.Models.Expense>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@foreach (Expense e in Model)
{
    <div class="m-4">
        <div class="col"> .....   </div>
    </div>
}
```

Компилим и идем в браузер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: где делся класс `m-4` и почему в браузере я его не наблюдаю? Так же не понятно ведет себя некоторые другие классы, а именно: `d-flex`, `d-inline-flex`, `col`, `row` и другие....

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал, самописные классы или другие оформления хранить в site.css, во первых они приоритетнее, во-вторых легче при отладке, а еще  в asp-net-core есть такая вещь как EnvironmentTagHelper которая иногда влияет на отображение стилей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в том, что нужно поставить версию 4.0.0